# Java identifier expected

Tags: java

Am writing a program that allows two Superheros to fight. The first class has compiled correctly, however the main is not. I am getting the same errors on line 9 and 18  expected. Am hoping someone could help me.

The Fight Class:

```
    public class Fight {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        Superhero Spiderman = new Superhero();
        Superhero TheHumanTorch = new Superhero(21);
    }

    public TheHumanTorch fight(Spiderman){
    System.out.Println(TheHumanTorch);
    }

    private void powerUp(int amount) {
    int amount = 100;
    Spiderman Strength = Strength + amount; 
    }

    public TheHumanTorch fight(Spiderman){
    System.out.Println(Spiderman);
    }

}
```

The Superhero Class:

```
public class Superhero { 
    public String Name; 
    private int Strength; 

    public Superhero(String n,int s) { 
        Name = n; 
        Strength = s; 
    } 

    public Superhero(String n) { 
        Name = n; 
        Strength = 10; 
    } 

    private void PowerUp(int amount) { 
        Strength = Strength + amount; 
    } 

    public Superhero fight(Superhero opponet) { 
        if (this.Strength > opponet.Strength) { 
            return this; 
        } else { 
            return opponet; 
        } 
    } 

    public String toString() {  
        return "Superhero"; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: public class Superhero {
 
 public String Name;
 private int Strength;

public Superhero(String n,int s) {
 
 Name = n;
 Strength = s;
 
}
 
public Superhero(String n) {
 
 Name = n;
 Strength = 10; 
}
 
private void PowerUp(int amount) {
 
 Strength = Strength + amount;
 
}

public Superhero fight(Superhero opponet) {
 
if (this.Strength > opponet.Strength) {
 
 return this;
} 
    else {
 return opponet;
 }

}
 public String toString() {  
   return "Superhero";
   
  
 }

}

Comment: You lack knowledge of elementary Java. I suggest that you read a Java tutorial before starting asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

In line 9 and 18:

```
public TheHumanTorch fight(Spiderman){
```

You did not define spiderman.
You could do it like this:

```
public void fight(Superhero superHero){
```

---

Other issues with your codes include:

- defining the same method twice (fight method defined twice in `main`)
- since your fight method is general, you probably want to give a more generic variable name like "superHero" instead of "spiderman". (As the current hero won't always be fighting a spiderman)
- the return type for method `fight` could just be `void`
- if you need to return the winner of the fight, it should be `Superhero` and not `TheHumanTorch`
- `Spiderman Strength = Strength + amount;` will give you an error. strength is `int`. You could just do `this.strength += amount;`
- Your `fight()` method in `SuperHero` class is **biased**. It situation of a tie in strength, the opponent was always win. You can create a condition for a tie in strength.
- You are defining the `fight` and various methods all over again in the main.

There is no need to do that. Just create an instance of `SuperHero` and call the methods from the instance:

```
//In main
SuperHero hero1= new SuperHero("Spiderman");
SuperHero hero2= new SuperHero("Batman");
hero1.fight(hero2);    //Let Spiderman fight with Batman
```

Comment: Also note that flight method is defined twice, with no return value.

Comment: @YoungHobbit Yes, there are a lot of problems in his codes. He gave a return type for `fight()`, but his return type is wrong.